# Dynamics of the gain/attenuation $k(t)$ in the ODE-system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, nonlinear-dynamics

Given system of equation:

\begin{cases} \frac{dx_1(t)}{dt}= \frac{df}{dx_1} \\ \frac{dx_2(t)}{dt}+x_2(t)=k(t) \cdot \frac{d^2f}{d^2x_1} \\ \frac{dk(t)}{dt}=??? \end{cases}

where $x_1(t),x_2(t),k(t)$ - variables, $f$ - any unimodal function, for experiment $f=\operatorname{sech}(x_1)$.

Variable $k(t)$ has a special purpose. It acts as a "*gain/attenuation*" factor.

**Task**: construct dynamic of the third equation ($???$) in such a way that $\nabla_{x_1}^2f \rightarrow -1$, regardless of the function $f$.

Comment: So $f$ here is a univariate function? Can't we replace $\nabla_{x_1}$ simply with $\mathrm{D}_{x_1}$ ?

Comment: @K.defaoite yes, it's just gradient $\frac{df}{dx_1}$ and hessian $\frac{d^2f}{d^2x_1}$

Comment: What do you mean that $\nabla_{x_1}^2f \rightarrow -1$?

Comment: There is no such $k$ based on the current dynamics as state $x_1$ is uncontrollable (unaffected by the input $k$). It is possible you missed an $x_2$ in the $x_1$ dynamics.

Comment: @Rollen please see, that's what I want

\begin{cases} \frac{dx_1(t)}{dt}= \frac{df}{dx_1} \\ \frac{dx_2(t)}{dt}+x_2(t)=k(t) \cdot \frac{d^2f}{d^2x_1} \\ \frac{dk(t)}{dt}=x_2(t)+1 \end{cases}

$f=sech(x_1-1)$

Comment: @xpaul This means that hessian should strive for $-1$.

Answer (score 1):

Let me rewrite your system a bit more compactly yet explicitly,

$$
\begin{aligned}
\dot{x}_1(t) &= f'(x_1(t)), \\
\dot{x}_2(t) &= -x_2(t) + k(t) f''(x_1(t)),
\end{aligned}
$$

where we'll take $k: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ to be any control law. Unfortunately, there exists initial conditions $x_1(0)$ and functions $f$ where no such $k$ exists to make $f''(x_1)\to -1.$ The state $x_1$ isn't controllable. We can see that the $x_1(t)$ dynamics is entirely determined by $x_1(t).$ It is an independent subsystem whose dynamics can be resolved independent of $k(t).$

So, for example, consider the (unimodal) bump function
$$
  f(x)
    = \left\{
    \begin{array}{lll}
      \mathrm{exp}\left(-\frac{1}{1 - x^2}\right), & \quad & \mathrm{if}\; x \in (-1,1)\\
      0, & \quad & \mathrm{otherwise}
    \end{array}
    \right.
$$
Although the dynamics are going to be locally asymptotically stable around the equilibrium $x_1 = 0$ where $f$ attains it maximum, they will not be in the region where $f'(x_1) = 0.$ If you are looking at minimums, just flip $f$ and make the same observation.

Comment: This code in Mathematica implements what I need (we do not need to pay attention to the quality of transients yet).

Comment: `Clear["Derivative"]`
`ClearAll["Global*"]`
`pars = {xs = -1, xe = 1/2};f = Exp[-(x1[t] - xe)^2]`
`Parallelize[
 sys = NDSolve[{x1'[t] == D[f, x1[t]], 
    x2'[t] + x2[t] == k[t] D[f, {x1[t], 2}], k'[t] == (x2[t] + 1), 
    x1[0] == xs, x2[0] == 0, k[0] == 1}, {x1, x2, k}, {t, 0, 500}]]`
`Plot[{Evaluate[x1[t] /. sys], xe}, {t, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> Full, 
 PlotPoints -> 100]`
`Plot[{Evaluate[k[t] /. sys]}, {t, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> Full, 
 PlotPoints -> 100]`
`Plot[{Evaluate[x2[t] /. sys], -1}, {t, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> Full, 
 PlotPoints -> 100]`

Comment: Now let's look at the results. 1 picture - variable $x_1$. 2 picture is the filtered variable $x_2$, which should go to state $-2$, but I made it come to state $-1$. Picture 3 - the scaling factor $k(t)$, which was selected in such a way as to make $-1$ out of $-2$. 

[https://ibb.co/wy8kyyD](https://ibb.co/wy8kyyD)

[https://ibb.co/D8nkxrL](https://ibb.co/D8nkxrL)

[https://ibb.co/dBZCZY7](https://ibb.co/dBZCZY7)

Comment: Still, is it true, the system implements the functions assigned to it? Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: I tested this with different initial conditions and did not find one under which it would not work.

Comment: Pick the function $f$ as i defined and choose an initial condition where $x_1>1$ and it will not converge to a maxima (or negate it for minima). @dtn

Comment: Now I understand what you mean. No, I don't use such functions in my research. They are all continuous and unimodal. Therefore, let's not consider the class you proposed.  @Rollen

Comment: That function is continuous. Moreover, its $C^\infty$ and unimodal. What class are you considering? Analytic?

Comment: @dtn it seems to be true if $f$ is real analytic but my answer stands. It has nothing to do with $k(t)$. $k(t)$ has no effect on the behaviour of $x_1$.

Comment: Yes, we are talking about analytic functions. Most of the objects I work with are described by functions that are not specified in a piecewise form.As for "$k(t)$ has no effect on the behavior of $x_1$" - everything is correct, and should not have (at least for now). The task of the coefficient $k(t)$ is to scale the variable $x_2$. But this leads to the question - is it possible to somehow artificially force to influence $k(t)$ on $x_1$? @Rollen

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123936/discussion-between-rollen-and-dtn).